# QEMU/KVM, virt-manager - Unable to complete install: error creating macvtap interface macvtap0@eno1 (52:54:00:1a:e1:3b): Operation not supported'

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, kvm, gentoo, qemu

I am trying to create a virtual machine with QEMU/KVM using virt-manager. I am using gentoo linux with kernel 4.12.0-rc7 mainline. Using a virtual network interface at all causes the following error.

```
Unable to complete install: 'error creating macvtap interface macvtap0@eno1 (52:54:00:1a:e1:3b): Operation not supported'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 88, in cb_wrapper
    callback(asyncjob, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/create.py", line 2288, in _do_async_install
    guest.start_install(meter=meter)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/guest.py", line 461, in start_install
    doboot, transient)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/guest.py", line 396, in _create_guest
    self.domain = self.conn.createXML(install_xml or final_xml, 0)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/libvirt.py", line 3591, in createXML
    if ret is None:raise libvirtError('virDomainCreateXML() failed', conn=self)
libvirtError: error creating macvtap interface macvtap0@eno1 (52:54:00:1a:e1:3b): Operation not supported
```

The settings for the network interface are:

- Network Source: Host device eno1: macvtap,
- Source mode: Bridge,
- Device model: virtio,
- Virtual port: not set

`eno1` is the name of my ethernet device.

Changing settings does not seem to help much, other than completely removing the network device which leads to a different, unrelated error, which I'm not sure if I will create a new post for.

I think that the error would be caused either by CONFIG_MACTVAP not being enabled in the kernel, which was the issue i was having before.

So, I enabled this and recompiled the kernel, but the setting was not to be found in `menuconfig` and I had to add it manually to `.config` (not the best idea, but the kernel accepted it as valid.) I do not think that `mactvap` is a kernel module so if it is I do not know what it what it is called as "mactvap" is not a module, and I set `CONFIG_MACTVAP` to `y` anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You will find the setting here:

Device Drivers --->

Network Device Support --->

<

> MAC-VLAN support

<

> MAC-VLAN based tap driver  (CONFIG_MACVTAP)